# Report preview not showing hardcoded XML field value

Tags: birt

I have an xml file with a simple structure like the following.
[image]

The following is what I have configured for my data set retrieval for the name attribute called 'CLNNAME'. And the value 'Hello' is displayed when previewing the report.

[image]

Then I have the following which is the one I want use but for some reason it does not display the value when previewing the report. Any shed of light into why the weird behaviour occurs when attribute names are hardcoded. Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.
[image]